# Is there a way in XPath 3.1 (not XQuery) to sort the results?

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-3.1

[I've looked through the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/) and can't find anything. But I thought sorting was supported in 3.1.

**Update** (sorry, I have a tendency to assume people can read my mind and I don't list enough details):

We're doing this in Java so we call:

```
XPathCompiler.compile(query);
XPathExecutable.load()
```

So our query is normally "/root/employees/employee" to get a list of all employees ([from Southwind.xml](https://www.windwardstudios.com/extras/southwind-datasources)).

To put it in SQL-ish terms, we then want to give our users the ability to do something like this:

"/root/employees/employee order by lastname descending, firstname ascending".

Based on the answer below, how do I pass this in Java code? [I see this example](https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/functions/fn/sort.html), but that I don't think is Java code (if it is, I don't understand the syntax).

And, can it sort on multiple nodes (ie sort on firstname if lastnames are equal)?

[Put in a more detailed question with sample code here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63100310/how-do-i-call-fnsort-in-saxon-from-java-with-multiple-sort-keys)

Comment: You must pass the required sorting keys and directions as parameters to the transformation. How to pass parameters to a transformation is implementation - dependent and varies from one XSLT processor to another. Please, read the documentation of the XSLT processor that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, see [**`fn:sort`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-sort) in [XPath and XQuery Functions and Operators 3.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/):

> **Summary**
>
> Sorts a supplied sequence, based on the value of a sort key supplied as a function.
>
> **Signatures**
>
> ```
> fn:sort($input as item()*) as item()*
>
> fn:sort($input as item()*, $collation as xs:string?) as item()*
>
> fn:sort($input     as item()*,
>         $collation as xs:string?,
>         $key       as function(item()) as xs:anyAtomicType*) as item()*
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> **Examples**
>
> The expression `fn:sort((1, 4, 6, 5, 3))` returns `(1, 3, 4, 5, 6)`.
>
> [...]

Comment: I updated my question based on your answer. I think fn:sort is what I need, but can't figure out how to call it in Java. TIA.